# How to get a value from function javascript and print it to the chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I get stuck when I try to print my result or value from
function on javascript to the chart. This is how I call my function from javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
           var testModel = id3(examples_personality,'kepribadian',features_personality);
           document.getElementById("akurasi").innerText = calcError(samples_personality,testModel,'kepribadian');
});

</script>
```

and I try to print the result like this :

```
<span id='akurasi'></span>
```

it's work fine if I use it on html, the value show up, but
when I try to use for the chart, it does not work. this is my code chart:

```
 // Data Training Chart
new Chart(document.getElementById("Data-Training-chart"), {
    type: 'polarArea',
    data: {
      labels: ["Data Training (%)", "Data Testing (%)"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "jumlah ",
          backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#ff4137"],
          data: [<span id='akurasi'></span>,100]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      legend: { display: false },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Data Training'
      }
    }
});
```

For information I using chartjs for the chart from this : [Link chart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this [doc-side](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/polar.html#data-structure) states you have to use an array of data points (numbers), but within your `data` the first item is not a number:

```
data: [<span id='akurasi'></span>,100]
```

You can query this value by using `getElementById` for instance:

```
data: [+document.getElementById("akurasi").innerText,100]
```

It should work if your `calcError` function returns a numeric value to show it with `akurasi`:

```
<span id='akurasi'>35</span>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Hello!</title>
</head>

<body>

<canvas id="chart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
<span id='akurasi'></span>

</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
           // ...
           document.getElementById("akurasi").innerText = 35;
           
           var chart = setupChart();
           // you can do whatever you want with this chart here...
           
 });

 function setupChart(){

    return new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
        type: 'polarArea',
        data: {
          labels: ["Data Training (%)", "Data Testing (%)"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "jumlah ",
              backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#ff4137"],
              data: [+document.getElementById("akurasi").innerText,100]
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          legend: { display: false },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Data Training'
          }
        }
    });

 }

</script>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i try it but when i run it and i inspect element, the code still print as "+document.getElementById("akurasi").innerText," not the value of the function calcError. the value absolutely numeric value because i try to print it to the html code and its show up.

Comment: Do you setup your chart after $(document).ready has fired? I just provied an example to show that getElementById should work.

Comment: it work because you have a value on this <span id='akurasi'>35</span>, but when i try it just like this <span id='akurasi'></span> (because the value from get from this : document.getElementById("akurasi").innerText = calcError(samples_personality,testModel,'kepribadian');) but it's doesn't work.

Comment: Refresh my answer, please, I hope it helps you more now. Just for information: You can run my example by clicking onto "Run code snippet"